# How to get versionName inside buildTypes gradle Android

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I have configured 2 build types like this:

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            versionNameSuffix "-prod"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.prod
            archivesBaseName "$versionName"
        }

        dev {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            versionNameSuffix "-dev"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.dev
            archivesBaseName "$versionName"
        }
}
```

The problem is that I get this error: `> Could not get unknown property 'versionName'`

Why is this not working? The problem occurs on archivesBaseName and seems that $versionName is not recognised

Comment: because it's not part of `buildTypes.xxx` but `defaultConfig` ... it is not avaible there because `versionName` is not ready yet as it depends on crossing `buildTypes` with `productFlavors`

Answer (score -1):

Try this one :

VersionName is flavorDimensions which is define in **defaultConfig**. Version Name field capture data from defaultConfig.

First of all android give priority of defaultConfig data then it override flavors data if data is same.

```
flavorDimensions "versionCode"
flavorDimensions "versionName"
flavorDimensions "appId"
productFlavors {
    UAT {
        dimension "versionCode"
        dimension "versionName"
        dimension "appId"
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"https://www.google.com/staging/app/api/v1/"'
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_LOCAL_DEV", "false"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_UAT", "true"
    }
    QA {
        dimension "versionCode"
        dimension "versionName"
        dimension "appId"
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"https://www.google.com/staging/app/api/v1/"'
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_LOCAL_DEV", "false"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_UAT", "false"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post only code without explanation how this would help OP